# Como colocar um delay dentro de outro delay

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um jogo de tabuleiro, ele está funcionando tudo certinho, porém, gostaria que ele ativasse mini jogos de acordo com a posição que o jogador parar.

Isso também está funcionando, o que não ta funcionando é o fato de que ele executa tudo antes mesmo de começar o delay de  movimento que utilizo pra fazer o personagem se mover.

Aqui é onde a movimentação acontece.

```
var i = 1;                                  //  set your counter to 1
var fimloop;
function myLoop () {                    //  create a loop 
    function setTimeout(function () {               //  call a 3s setTimeout when the loop is called

        posicao++;

        $('#contaPosicoes').val(posicao).trigger('change');
        moveRight(circle,posicao);      //  your code here
        i++;                                //  increment the counter
        if ((i < evt+1)&&(posicao<38)) {  //  if the counter < 10, call the loop function
            myLoop();                       //  ..  again which will trigger another 
        //fimloop = false;
        }                                   //  ..  setTimeout()
    }, 300);
                  fimloop = true;
}

myLoop();
```

Gostaria de fazer qualquer coisa só depois que esse loop terminar.

Comment: Alan, não precisa colocar "Resolvido" no título. O correto é aceitar a resposta que resolveu o seu problema, veja [no FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como fazê-lo.

Comment: Foi mal, essa foi minha primeira pergunta e acabei não lendo as regras pela pressa de entregar esse job, obrigado a você também.

Comment: Para aceitar a resposta clique no 'V' abaixo do numero de votações que vai ficar verde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma, o código esta comentado explicando o seu funcionamento.

```js
//Proxima função
function proximaFuncao(){
  console.log('Executando proximaFuncao');
}

//Usei o contado para simular um loop, mas adapte de acordo com a sua logica 
var contador = 0;

function myLoop () {
    console.log('Executando myLoop');
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (contador<= 3) {
            contador++;
            myLoop();        
        }else{//Condição para a chamada da próxima função
           proximaFuncao();
        } 
    }, 300);
}

myLoop();
```

Comment: Wictor é exatamente o que estava precisando, muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Por favor, marque o "V" que sinaliza que esta é a sua resposta :)